# do_action returns value before it's position

Tags: php, wordpress

I have following code in a plugin:

```php
    public static function addFooterScript() {

        add_action( 'wp_footer', function () {

            $primary   = has_action( 'spx_color_primary' ) ? do_action( 'spx_color_primary' ) : 'teal';
            $secondary = has_action( 'spx_color_secondary' ) ? do_action( 'spx_color_secondary' ) : 'pink';

            echo '
                <spx-section-settings
                color-primary="' . $primary . '"
                color-secondary="' . $secondary . '">
                </spx-section-settings>
                <script 
                id="spx-footer">
                ' . file_get_contents( SPX_DIR . '/assets/js/footer.js' ) . '
                </script>';

        } );

    }
```

And in my theme, I am calling it like that:

```php
add_action( 'spx_color_primary', function () {
    echo 'blue';
} );
```

However, the return value from the action is appearing before the element:

[image]

I am clueless, why is that happening?

Comment: Because you are telling it to in your theme: `echo 'blue';` What are you trying to get it to do, if you do t want it to print out the word “blue”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a filter instead of an action. Change the action to filter by the below code the default value will be teal. And the filter will change it to blue.

```
$primary = apply_filters( 'spx_color_primary', 'teal');
```

Use this in your functions.php

```
function example_callback_to_change_color( $string ) {
    $string = 'blue';
    return $string;
}
add_filter( 'spx_color_primary', 'example_callback_to_change_color', 10, 1 );
```

To understand more about action and filters [Difference Between Filter and Action Hooks?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1007/difference-between-filter-and-action-hooks)